# Optimising mapply'ied function over large data frame

Tags: r, optimization, mapply, date-difference

I have following created function for my work purposes:

```
monthsCounter <- function(date1, date2) {
  if (date2 < date1) {
    warning("Can't calculate result if second date is older than first date")
  } else {
    date1_Y <- as.numeric(format(date1, '%Y'))
    date2_Y <- as.numeric(format(date2, '%Y'))
    date1_M <- as.numeric(format(date1, '%m'))
    date2_M <- as.numeric(format(date2, '%m'))
    if (date2_Y == date1_Y) {
      date2_M - date1_M
    } else if (date2_M < date1_M) {
      max(0, date2_Y - date1_Y - 1)*12 + 12 - date1_M + date2_M
    } else {
      max(0, date2_Y - date1_Y)*12 + date2_M - date1_M
    }
  }
}
```

In a nutshel it counts months between two dates regardless of month date.
When I `mapply` it on my data frame:

```
allData$monthsSinceIssue <- mapply(monthsCounter, allData$start_month, allData$Date)
```

it takes very long time to calculate.

**Question:** Do you have any suggestions on how can I optimize my function to make it calculate faster?

---

**UPDATE:** Based on @Sotos and @MrGumble suggestion I ended up with this function:

```
monthsCounter <- function(date1, date2) {
  date1_Y <- as.numeric(format(date1, '%Y'))
  date2_Y <- as.numeric(format(date2, '%Y'))
  date1_M <- as.numeric(format(date1, '%m'))
  date2_M <- as.numeric(format(date2, '%m'))
  ifelse(date2 < date1, NA,
         ifelse(date2_Y == date1_Y, date2_M - date1_M,
                ifelse(date2_M < date1_M, max(0, date2_Y - date1_Y - 1)*12 + 12 - date1_M + date2_M, max(0, date2_Y - date1_Y)*12 + date2_M - date1_M)))
}
```

### which decreased my calculation time from **3.5minutes to 2 seconds!**

**UPDATE2:** I stumbled upon issue which @MrGumble was probably pointing on. Cases when `date2 - date1 > 1`.
Thus had to update function to this:

```
monthsCounter <- function(date1, date2) {
  date1_Y <- as.numeric(format(date1, '%Y'))
  date2_Y <- as.numeric(format(date2, '%Y'))
  date1_M <- as.numeric(format(date1, '%m'))
  date2_M <- as.numeric(format(date2, '%m'))
  ifelse(date2 < date1, NA,
         ifelse(date2_Y == date1_Y, date2_M - date1_M,
                ifelse(date2_M < date1_M, pmax(0, date2_Y - date1_Y - 1)*12 + 12 - date1_M + date2_M, pmax(0, date2_Y - date1_Y)*12 + date2_M - date1_M)))
}
```

Basically changed `max` to `pmax`.

Comment: If you use `ifelse` which is vectorized (rather than `if else`), then you should be able to apply it without any loops (`monthsCounter(date1, date2)`)

Comment: @Sotos can you post this to answer, as it solved my problem? I would like to award bounty to you.
The increase is actually huge. Calculation time decreased from 3.5 minutes to 2 seconds. I suppose the calculation time for my function increases exponentially if I increase my data size.

Comment: Great job @MiksL, you've just demonstrated how R works natively with vectors! Just wait till you find the cases that exceptions to this... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R inherently works very well with vectors. You function could easily accept the two columns as arguments:

```
allData$monthsSinceIssue <- monthsCounter(allData$start_month, allData$Date)
```

Although you would have to change `max` to `pmax`. Also do as Sotos suggest (update to `ifelse` function).
Finally I would suggest you return `NA` instead of a warning.

Comment: It'd be interesting to do some benchmarking. I was going to do it myself but you beat me in answering :). (If you want to get some dates use this `sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2017/01/01'), by="day"), 1000)`)